# Is there a good non-blocking pattern for loading high-res images on the web?

Tags: css, performance

I have a stylesheet (`hi-dpi.css`) and it contains a bunch of higher-resolution assets, many of which are inline (data URIs). But currently it blocks page render.

What’s the best way to address this?

Perhaps write the `<link rel=stylesheet>` tag after page `load`?

Comment: That sounds like a good idea - have you tried that?

Comment: @antisanity Base64 encoding adds on average 33% to the file size, but gzipping brings it back, sometimes to less than the original.

Comment: @antisanity Would never base64 a big jpeg or something, but we have some seriously small, monochrome, ImageOptim-crushed PNGs that are maybe between 300B – 1KB each. And there’s some spriting.

Comment: @David No, I haven’t yet. Wanted to see what others were thinking first *before* doing a bunch of x-browser testing!

Answer (score 0):

Put this script in the head, it should load it without blocking ([test](http://stevesouders.com/cuzillion/?c0=hc1dtff4_0_f)).

```
setTimeout(function () {
    var el = document.createElement('link'),
        sc = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    el.rel = 'stylesheet';
    el.href = 'hi-dpi.css';
    sc.parentNode.insertBefore(el, sc);
}, 30);
```

You may have to split it in parts if its too large, so it downloads in parallel.

Comment: The point to loading CSS at the head of the document http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html is to give the page the information it needs for rendering everything else (placements and widths and the like) __also, agreed on the splitting into more parts, but that defeats the purpose of sprites, no?__

Comment: @jcolebrand it contains only images, so the layout will still be visible, only the images will load later if you have slow connection.

Comment: Not according to my reading from the OP. It seems to contain _other things as well_ besides the hi-res DPI images. However, if he's already doing all the things I suggested, then yes, I would say that yours is the only other option after mine.

Comment: The only things in hi-dpi.css would be some combination of inlined images and references to sprited image files, and the requisite `background-size` declarations. Layout would be unaffected.

Comment: background-size delcarations _are_ layout.

Answer (score 0):

I have to ask this, before I go much further, but is it really necessary to have a lot of "hi res assets" in CSS? I mean, maybe it's just me, but ...

So here's my suggestion: Load everything BUT the data-uri in the "original stylesheet" (so that the page render still gets the image sizes and whatnot that may be declared) but have a second filesheet at the END of the page that has all actual data-uri in there. **literally the last element of the page**

I'm not ENTIRELY sure that will work, but it SHOULD help alleviate the problem.

The reason is because the rendering engine needs to know things like widths, CSS box model, etc, to render correctly, but rendering images tends to take longer for the graphics engine (this is my understanding) plus I'm willing to be the file is itself quite large, so it takes time to download. So by giving the page all the CSS box-model etc, it can do the layout, and load the images at the end.

You might want to read this: http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html

And here's my ALTERNATE option:

Load low-res images in the current CSS (so the page shows something) and load the hi-res images in the footer CSS so that they *overwrite* the low-res images.

Comment: No, I read including a stylesheet ANYWHERE blocks javascript because the script may be depending on certain styles to have been applied :/

Comment: I've never heard that, actually. Why would javascript block on styles? Javascript is interpreted inline when it's encountered, and is not dependent on stylesheets on any engine I've come across. Can you recall where you read that?